# Add custom field to media attachment image attribute in post editor

Tags: custom-post-types, customization, custom-field, attachments, attachment-fields-to-edit

I have the following filter, but do not know how to add custom attributes to image field, when attaching media to post.

example

```
<img data-ext-link-title="" data-ext-link-url="">
```

functions.php

```
function pp_external_link_edit( $form_fields, $post ) {
    $form_fields['pp-external-link-title'] = array(
        'label' => 'External Link Title',
        'input' => 'text',
        'value' => get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'pp_external_link_title', true ),
        'helps' => 'Link for button at bottom of pretty photo modal',
    );

    $form_fields['pp-external-link-url'] = array(
        'label' => 'External Link URL',
        'input' => 'text',
        'value' => get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'pp_external_link_url', true ),
        'helps' => 'Link for button at bottom of pretty photo modal',
    );

    return $form_fields;
}

add_filter( 'attachment_fields_to_edit', 'pp_external_link_edit', 10, 2 );

function pp_external_link_save( $post, $attachment ) {
    if( isset( $attachment['pp-external-link-title'] ) )
        update_post_meta( $post['ID'], 'pp_external_link_title', $attachment['pp-external-link-title']);

    if( isset( $attachment['pp-external-link-url'] ) )
        update_post_meta( $post['ID'], 'pp_external_link_url', $attachment['pp-external-link-url']);

    return $post;
}

add_filter( 'attachment_fields_to_save', 'pp_external_link_save', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: You could save yourself a buttload of headache by just installing Advanced Custom Fields https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/. Which has an interface to very easily setup fields for anywhere, including media attachments.

Comment: Here's a link to the ACF page for adding and retrieving custom fields on media posts.

https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/adding-fields-media-attachments/

Comment: ACF adds custom fields to the attachment details popup in the media library, but it does not add them to the Image details popup when editing the image in the edit post page, which I think is what the OP asked for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wonder if you want to modify the HTML of the inserted image, with the `image_send_to_editor` or `get_image_tag` filters?

If that's the case, then here's one example:

```
/**   
 * Add the data-ext-link-title and data-ext-link-url attributes to inserted images. 
 */

add_filter( 'image_send_to_editor',
    function( $html, $id, $caption, $title, $align, $url, $size, $alt )
    {    
        if( $id > 0 )
        {
            $ext_title = get_post_meta( $id, 'pp_external_link_title', true ); 
            $ext_url   = get_post_meta( $id, 'pp_external_link_url',   true ); 
            $data  = sprintf( ' data-ext-link-title="%s" ', esc_attr( $ext_title ) );
            $data .= sprintf( ' data-ext-link-url="%s" ',   esc_url( $ext_url )    );
            $html = str_replace( "<img src", "<img{$data}src", $html );
        }
        return $html;
    }
, 10, 8 );
```

Here I assume you want empty `data-ext-link-title` or `data-ext-link-url` attributes, if the corresponding meta values are empty or missing.

Hopefully you can adjust this to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

I was doing something similar the other day and simply could not get attachment_fields_to_save to work no matter what I tried.

I ended up using the edit_attachment filter instead along with code like the following:

```
public function action_edit_attachment( $attachment_id ) {
    # Check to make sure we were sent by the side of the media editor, not by the real edit form
    # - if the real edit form was used, action would be editpost instead
    if ( isset($_REQUEST['action']) ) {
        $our_fields = array(
            'pp-external-link-title' => 'text',
            'pp-external-link-url' => 'text'
        );
        foreach ( $our_fields as $field_name => $input_type ) {
            if ( isset( $_REQUEST['attachments'][$attachment_id]["{$field_name}"] ) ) {
                switch ( "{$input_type}" ) {
                    case 'text':
                        $value = stripcslashes($_REQUEST['attachments'][$attachment_id]["{$field_name}"]);
                        update_post_meta( $attachment_id, "{$field_name}", $value );
                        break;
                    default:
                        # Not implemented
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return $attachment_id;
}
add_filter( 'edit_attachment', 'action_edit_attachment' );
```

If you only want it to save from the media screen, you could change the _REQUEST check

```
if ( isset($_REQUEST['action']) && 'save-attachment-compat' == "{$_REQUEST['action']}" ) {
```

Or from the full attachment post editor

```
if ( isset($_REQUEST['action']) && 'editpost' == "{$_REQUEST['action']}" ) {
```

Anywise, I had no luck with the older method ... and saw at least a few people had just as much difficulty with it as I did.